# How can I detect layout type from object?

Tags: android, android-layout

l have an object that can contain any type of layout. How can I detect layout type ?
I have an idea only with try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
final ViewGroup layout = yourObject.getMyLayout();
if (layout instanceof LinearLayout) {
  //do something
}
else if (layout instanceof TableLayout){
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try [instanceof](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/instanceof.html) operator

layout instanceof Linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

Little bit clunky but you could have an if statement like this

```
if(this.getCurrentFocus().getId() ==  R.layout.myLayout)
 {
   String layoutType = "Linear";
 }
```

or do whatever you need to with the result